# interpolating function over dates

Tags: interpolation, date-and-time

I've got a bunch of readings at various dates and times.  I'd like to be able to interpolate and then integrate over, say days.  I can do this by converting my date/time to `AbosluteTime` and get the interpolating function that way.  Then by integrating and plugging in seconds as my limits of integration I get what I want.

Also, since seconds in really finer than I need, I convert all of the `AbsoluteTimes` to the number of hours since the first reading.

I was wondering if there might be a way to do this directly using dates.  For what it's worth, my readings last for about 2 months and the values are between about 90 and 300.

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
 x[[1 ;; 5]]
```

> {{{2014, 8, 4, 10, 36, 0.}, 257.},{{2014, 8, 4, 16, 28, 0.}, 385.},
>
> {{2014, 8, 4, 22, 53, 0.}, 176.},
>   {{2014, 8, 5, 6, 52, 0.}, 148.}, {{2014, 8, 5, 11, 19, 0.}, 192.}}

Comment: Could you please add an example of your data?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong edit. Anyway, a +1 question :)

Comment: @eldo no problem about the edit.  I appreciate your looking over the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this:

```
data = {{{2014, 8, 4, 10, 36, 0.}, 257.}, {{2014, 8, 4, 16, 28, 0.}, 385.},
 {{2014, 8, 4, 22, 53, 0.}, 176.}, {{2014, 8, 5, 6, 52, 0.}, 148.},
 {{2014, 8, 5, 11, 19, 0.}, 192.}};
```

1) Convert dates to absolute times:

```
data[[All, 1]] = AbsoluteTime /@ data[[All, 1]];
f1 = Interpolation@data;

f1[AbsoluteTime@{2014,8,4,10,40}]
```

> `261.669`

2) With `TimeSeries` (v10)

```
ts = TimeSeries[data];
ts[{2014, 8, 4, 10, 40}]
```

> `258.455`

The `TimeSeries` interpolation uses first order by default but can be changed by changing the `ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", opts}` option in the `TimeSeries` function.

```
ts = TimeSeries[data, ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 3}];
ts[{2014, 8, 4, 10, 40}]
```

> `261.669`

To integrate over:

```
NIntegrate[ts[t], {t, AbsoluteTime[{2014, 8, 4, 10, 40}], AbsoluteTime[{2014, 8, 4,11}]}]
```

Comment: Looks like TimeSeries was a nice addition to version 10 - I like that method.

Comment: Incidentally, with `TimeSeries` it isn't necessary to use the "PathFunction".  Just evaluate directly on the date stamp.

Comment: @AndyRoss Sweet. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

Some sample data:

```
r = # - #[[1]] &@(Range[##, 3690] & @@ (AbsoluteTime[{#, {"Day", "Month", "YearShort"}}] & /@ 
                                                                         {"05/01/14", "05/03/14"}));
hours = N[r/3600];
data = Transpose[{hours, hours^2}];
```

Integrate:

```
f = Interpolation@data;
Integrate[f@x, {x, 0, Last@hours}]

(*9.45434*10^8*)
```